# Using jQuery to add an dropshadow on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a text on the homepage of an website i'm working on. The text can be changed an controlled using an CMS and thus is variable. What are my options of getting an dropshadow on this text? I've found an partial solution using [this](http://dropshadow.webvex.jux.com/) example. This doesn't exactly give me what i'm looking for. I see an shadow being created but it's not inline with the text.

This is how I used the dropshadow plugin;

```
$("#intro-tekst").dropShadow({ 
    left: 0, 
    top: 0, 
    opacity: 0.8, 
    blur: 2 
});
```

And this is the applied css to the part of the page i'm working on;

```
#intro-tekst
{
    color                   : #FFF;
    float                   : right;
    margin-top              : 130px;
    width                   : 730px;
    text-align              : center;
    font-size               : 22px;
}

#intro-tekst > h1
{
    text-transform          : uppercase;
    padding                 : 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin                  : 0px 25px 0px 0px;
    /*font-weight             : bold !important;*/
}
```

The html i'm working with looks as following;

```
<div id="intro-tekst" id="Introductie">
    <h1>Stijlvol in het nieuwe jaar!</h1>
    Naar de mooiste looks!
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong while creating this dropshadow? Or are the other solution available? One thing to note here that i'm using Cufon to style the text. I know it can be done with css3 but I need the website to be supported in IE7+, FF, Chrome and Safari and as far as I know this can't be done without using javscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Cufon for all your fonts then the easist thing is porbably to leverage Cufon's own [styling](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling) support for **text-shadow**

```
Cufon.replace('h1', { 
  color: '-linear-gradient(white, #bcdad3)', 
  fontFamily: 'TradeGothic', 
  textShadow: '2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12)' 
});
```

A more elaborate example is shown [here](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/examples/text-shadow.html).

Comment: +1 Never knew this was possible! Thanks for the example and provided link. Will test this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Only I can't blur the shadow. You know if this can be done?

Comment: never tried using blur, but their doc unfortunately contains this line "Offsets defined in units other than pixels are not supported, neither is blur".

Comment: thanks! Missed that line in the documentation. And again thanks for the quick and good answers:)

Comment: I have not tried it, but sIFR should actually support drop shadows with blur http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/sifr_3_hard_drop_shadows/

Answer (score 2):

Go here and create whatever you want, it will auto generate cross-browser css at best

### http://css3generator.com/

**ALL D BEST :)**

Comment: Judging by the browser icons shown text shadow hasn't got IE support?

Comment: i think IE7  and above support `text shadow` read this manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-shadow

Comment: The preview area doesn't seem to work when tried with text shadow in IE9, so I assume it doesn't work for IE.

Comment: @Jaymz you may be right; i have no such information regrading that. Thanks for the update. i hope above link will be helpful :)

Comment: @diEcho, tried your suggestion but indeed doesn't seem to do anything in IE. Tried in IE9 and used backwards compatibility mode to test for IE7 and IE8. God and usefull link though!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  id="Introductie">     
<h1 id="intro-tekst">Stijlvol in het nieuwe jaar!</h1> 
Naar de mooiste looks! </div>
```

? setting 2 id tags in 1 div?

Comment: An requirement our cms has. I'm aware it's semantically incorrect